# Clustering markers with google maps version 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have about 2400 markers that are being displayed on google maps version 3. The problem is that there are too many markers on the map and that is not a good visual representation. What is want to do is group that the markers (i.e. cluster them). I'm experiencing some issues regarding that. Below is my sample code.

```
function initialize() {
        var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 2,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            //marker:true
        };

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        //Get marker image
        var redMarker = 'Images/marker2.png';
        var greenMarker = 'Images/g48.png';
        var currentMarker;

        var gmarkers = [];

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];
            var mag = data.Magnitude;
            if (mag < 5) {
                currentMarker = greenMarker;
            }
            else if (mag >= 5) {
                currentMarker = redMarker;
            };
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title,
                icon: currentMarker
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                //Attaching a click event to the current marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent('Magnitude: ' + data.Magnitude + '<br />'
                                         + 'Location: ' + data.title);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
            gmarkers.push(marker);
        }
    }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);

    window.onload = function () { initialize();
}
```

Comment: _"I'm experiencing some issues"_ - what issues?

Comment: Infact the map doesn't display. And when i comment the line: 
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
The map displays with all the markers. I have already checked that the libraries needed are included.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue including any HTML/CSS required and some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I get a javascript error in your code as posted

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
```

on this line:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
```

The map variable is local to the initialize function. 
That line is outside of the initialize function, so the map variable isn't available to it.

Put it inside the initialize function (but after the markers have been parsed).

Comment: I tried what you said. Now only 1 marker is being displayed. Could you please update the above code?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue including any HTML/CSS required and some sample data.

Comment: There is no HTML, CSS or sample data in your posted question.  It won't run as is, how did you test it?

Comment: The coordinates are stored in a sql server database. I am retrieving the coordinates from the database and then plotting them on the map. And in my body i just have a div where the map will be displayed.

Comment: Ok i got it to working now. Silly mistake of missing a closing round bracket.